# Asterisk meaning in Haskell profiling?

Tags: haskell, profiling

What is the askterisk meaning that shows among the types when doing a heap residency profile (-hy)?

Comment: ["unknown type"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nh0okI1a1sQC&pg=PA568&lpg=PA568&dq=haskell+profiling+%22unknown+type%22&source=bl&ots=sYVLwcgYcU&sig=QfPDeG6bxH7JMWW9iMYsbFwciPg&hl=en&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=haskell%20profiling%20%22unknown%20type%22&f=false)...

Comment: @PaoloFalabella what's the difference between Blackhole and *?

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2003-April/005050.html

Comment: Large Blackhole area generally means you have more laziness.

Answer (score 2):

When you see an asterisk in your heap profile, try doing a -hd profile, which will actually give you a description, e.g. if the objects in question are closures on your stack, etc.